# Force form subject

Tags: php

I am trying to get the $subject = "Add my Fur Baby to Cape Breton Cares Contest"; to be the subject in the email as well. Would anyone know how I can do this. Thanks

```js
<?php
$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; 
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];  
$uploaded_file = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
$formcontent=" First Name: $first_name \n Fur Babies Name: $last_name \n Email: $email \n Subject: $subject \n Image: $uploaded_file";
$recipient = "contest@capebretoncares.com";
$subject = "Add my Fur Baby to Cape Breton Cares Contest";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header("Location: https://www.capebretoncares.com/p/thank-you/");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, use this code. `$subject` should be defined before `$formcontent`

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; 
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$recipient = "contest@capebretoncares.com";
$subject = "Add my Fur Baby to Cape Breton Cares Contest"; 
$uploaded_file = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
$formcontent=" First Name: ".$first_name." \n Fur Babies Name: ".$last_name." \n Email: ".$email." \n Subject: ".$subject." \n Image: ".$uploaded_file;
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header("Location: https://www.capebretoncares.com/p/thank-you/");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this does not work right now is because the `$subject` variable is set after the `$formcontent`, just move `$subject` before `$formcontent`:

```
$subject = "Add my Fur Baby to Cape Breton Cares Contest";
$formcontent = "First Name: $first_name \n Fur Babies Name: $last_name \n Email: 
$email \n Subject: $subject \n Image: $uploaded_file";
$recipient = "contest@capebretoncares.com";
```